# Angular2 select default first option

Tags: angular

How do i select the first option in a select by default in angular 2 the following code don't seems to work.

```
<select id="sType" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="params.searchType"> 
     <option *ngFor="let t of sTypes" [ngValue]="t.value" [attr.selected]="$index == 0 ? true : null">{{t.name}}</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can select first option by default using index value.

```
<select id="sType" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="params.searchType"> 
 <option   *ngFor="let t of sTypes; let i = index" [attr.value]="t.value" [attr.selected]="i == 0 ? true : null">{{t.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6):

This works for angular 4.1.3:

```
<option *ngFor="let t of sTypes; let i = index" [value]="t.value" [selected]="i==0">
```

Comment: Seems to not work with Angular 4.4.4 and model driven form.

Comment: index as i is proper these days

Answer (score 4):

One more solution is the custom directive, which will listen to `<option>`s list changes and select the first item if none selected.

```
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[mySelectFirstOption]'
})
export class SelectFirstOptionDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  private observer: MutationObserver;

  constructor(
      private elementRef: ElementRef,
      private renderer: Renderer2) {
    if ((elementRef.nativeElement.tagName || '').toLowerCase() !== 'select') {
      throw new Error('mySelectFirstOption directive can only be applied to <select> elements');
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => this.trySelectFirstOption(), 0);
    this.observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => this.trySelectFirstOption());
    const config: MutationObserverInit = { childList: true };
    this.observer.observe(this.elementRef.nativeElement, config);
  }

  private trySelectFirstOption() {
    const nativeElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    if (nativeElement.options.length > 0 && nativeElement.selectedIndex === -1) {
      this.renderer.setProperty(nativeElement, 'value', nativeElement.options[0].value);
      nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    }
  }
}
```

And then you can use it with `<select>` element like this:

```
<select ... mySelectFirstOption>
```

Comment: what if we have first element which is in disabled state like this. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-snyd5u?file=src/app/app.component.html
how can select first element which is "Shop Owner"

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE 2023 :**

```html
<option *ngFor="let value of values; let first = first"
    [value]="value" [selected]="first">
    {{item}}
</option>
```

**ORIGINAL ANWSER :**

Or simply like this :)

```html
<option *ngFor="let value of values; let i = index"
    [ngValue]="value" [attr.selected]="!i">
    {{item}}
</option>
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

try using this

```
<select id="sType" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="params.searchType" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"> 
     <option *ngFor="let t of sTypes" [Value]="t.value">{{t.name}}</option> 
</select>
```

in controller/component use-

```
this.params.searchType=sTypes[0]

onChange(updatedValue) {
this.params.searchType = updatedValue;
//other code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reactive form controls

You can also set value in component using rform.controls

```
this.rForm.controls['id'].setValue(this.array[0].id);
```

Comment: Was looking exactly for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you use *Model Driven Forms* you can set the selected default value of your `<select>` in your component (`ngOnInit()`)

componenet.file.ts

```
public fieldSelect : any;

ngOnInit(){
    ...
    this.fieldSelect= { key: "mySelect", label: "Example Select"};
    this.controlsConfig= [];
    this.controlsConfig[this.fieldSelect.key] =  [""];
    this.myFormGroup= this.formBuilder.group(this.controlsConfig);
...
}
```

component.file.html

```
<div class="col-md-2" [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
    <select (change)="onChangeTypeImp($event)" [formControlName]="fieldSelect.key">
       <option *ngFor="let item of items;" [value]="item">{{item}}</option>
   </select>                      
</div>
```

> Model-Driven Forms: While using directives in our templates gives us
>   the power of rapid prototyping without too much boilerplate, we are
>   restricted in what we can do. Reactive forms on the other hand, lets
>   us define our form through code and gives us much more flexibility and
>   control over data validation.+
>
> There is a little bit of magic in its simplicity at first, but after
>   you're comfortable with the basics, learning its building blocks will
>   allow you to handle more complex use cases.

[[example]](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/forms/model-driven/)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two things that cannot work together, as they conflict: ngModel and selected. If you bind  with params.searchType you have to initialize params.searchType to the default value you want:
    this.params.searchType = sTypes[0];

Answer (score 1):

This is from a robot simulator code kata found on exercism.org. This is more of a TypeScript solution. The view code as follows:

```
<select #robotSelect id='robotSelect' name='robotSelect' [(ngModel)]='robotId' size='5' style='width: 200px;'>
  <optgroup>
    <option *ngFor='let bot of factoryRobots'>{{ bot.id }}</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

In the TypeScript, get the # in the AfterViewInit lifecycle hook and set the zeroth option as selected:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
...
  robotId: string = '';
  robotSelect: HTMLSelectElement | undefined = undefined;
  //
  constructor( private _elementRef: ElementRef ) {
    ...
  }
  //
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.robotSelect = this._elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#robotSelect');
    if( this.robotSelect !== undefined ) {
      if( this.robotSelect.options.length > 0 ) {
        this.robotSelect.options[0].selected = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedCDM" >
    <option *ngFor="let cdm of CDMs;let i = index"  [ngValue]='cdm'>
                {{cdm.Name}}
    </option>
 </select>
```

CDMs is an array of objects, where an object has Id and Name as attribute. And selectedCDM is set to first element of CDMs array

Answer (score 0):

1) I hope this approach can help as well!

```
<select id="category" name="category" class="form-control" formControlName="category">
     <option [attr.selected]="true" [ngValue]="categories[0].id" >{{categories[0].name}}</option>
     <option *ngFor="let cat of categories.slice(1)" [ngValue]="cat.id">{{cat.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

2 ) If you are using a Form control you need just to set it like default value

```
 this.fgAddingProduct = new FormGroup({
        category: new FormControl(this.categories[0].id, [Validators.required]),
 });
```

And use a normal *ngFor

```
<select id="category" name="category" class="form-control" formControlName="category">
            <option *ngFor="let cat of categories" [ngValue]="cat.id">{{cat.name}}</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple example to select first option. To select other option, change number like i==0, i==1 or i==2 etc.

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [value]="item.name" [selected]="i == 0">
        {{item.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```