# radio button with same formcontrol name is getting selected together on click in angular7

Tags: javascript, html, angular, select, radio-button

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7aqzj2

```js
places = ['effil tower','new discover']

new FormGroup({place: new FormControl()});
```

```html
 <div *ngIf="places?.length > 0" class="col-12">
            <div style=" padding-top: 1em; ">
                <label  *ngFor="let place of places">
                    <input  formControlName="place" type="radio">{{place}}
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am trying to add the radio button with the same form-control name and the value is coming through services.

while doing so it has the same form-control name so getting selected both at a same time.

is there any way to differentiate both and select one at a time?

Comment: Sorry, but the question isn't really clear. Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Maybe a stackblitz to illustrate what exactly is happening.

Comment: please check below stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7aqzj2

Comment: I am trying to select one radio button but it is getting selected both

Comment: There are errors in your stackblitz demo. Dropdown values aren't loading. Please check.

Comment: sorry i missed to save.. try now

Comment: no there is no error .. i do have issue to show first index of array in dropdown..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use property binding for each option:

```
<input  formControlName="place" type="radio" [value]="place">
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. it worked.. just curious how I can make the first index of the array by default in the dropdown?

Comment: Glad to help! Sorry didn't get you. Which dropdown are you talking about?

Comment: Extend your *ngFor to pass the first value through `*ngFor="let place of places; let first = first;"`. And then set selected if first is true, `<option [selected]="first"></option>`

Comment: I do have 2 dropdowns in the screen.. by default I want to display the first index of the array.. for example, France  and Paris should be selected

Comment: @ Sam , I tried the same but not working as expected.. do you mean I need to created one more option field?

Comment: @atitpatel: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117375/angular2-select-default-first-option) can help.

Comment: This will do the trick : `<option *ngFor = "let country of countrydrodown; let j = index" 
                [attr.value] = "country.id" 
                [selected] = "j === 0">
                  {{country.name}} 
                  </option>
        </select>`

Answer (score 0):

The input needs to have a *value* defined. Additionally when you construct the FormGroup you can define a default value if you would like.

This question might help you more. [Angular 5 Reactive Forms - Radio Button Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078286/angular-5-reactive-forms-radio-button-group)

```html
 <div *ngIf="places?.length > 0" class="col-12">
            <div style=" padding-top: 1em; ">
                <label  *ngFor="let place of places">
                    <input  formControlName="place" type="radio" value=place>{{place}}
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
places = ['effil tower','new discover']

new FormGroup({place: new FormControl(this.places[0])});
```

```html
 <div *ngIf="places?.length > 0" class="col-12">
            <div style=" padding-top: 1em; ">
                <label  *ngFor="let place of places">
                    <input  formControlName="place" type="radio" [value]="place">{{place}}
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Hope this helps. [value]="place" and FormControl(this.places[0])